# Can't change magnet handler

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to change my magnet handler by using:

```
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet qbittorrent.desktop
```

I am getting an error:

```
Failed to load info for handler 'qbittorrent.desktop'
```

Please note the qbittorrent in installed. I've also tried using transmission with same results.

Comment: Anyone , Anyone ?

Answer (score 4):

The command to show the default program and alternative programs to open magnet links is:

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

Set your preferred app, for example:

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `man gvfs-mime` gvfs-mime has been deprecated and it is redirected to gio mime.

Issue the following command instead, it works just fine for me:

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet qbittorrent.desktop
```